# Why does the error occur in Text component?

Tags: react-native

Rendering the values retrieved from the server, and writing the code as below results in an undefined object error.

```js
export default Amount() {
    // ...
    const divideNum = (num:number) {
       return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
    // ...

    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{color: '#00f'}}>amount: {divideNum(userCoin)} dollars</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

However, if I use Template Literary as shown below, there will be no error.

```js
export default Amount() {
    // ...
    const divideNum = (num:number) {
       return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
    // ...

    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{color: '#00f'}}>{`amount ${divideNum(userCoin)} dollars`}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I wonder why the two cases work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have the method name wrong.
The actual method name in your code is `devideNum()` but in the  component you have it named `divideNum()`.

Not sure if that's the issue but this seems to be working -

`<Text >amount: {divideNum(123)} dollar</Text>`

Comment: Thank you, but the same problem occurs when I correct the function name.